# String comparison in C with operators

Tags: c, string, comparison

I can't compare between operators  and it takes 1 only input and then the program crashes.

```
char operatorValue;
do
{

    printf("\nEnter Operator:");
    scanf("%c", &operatorValue);

} while (strcmp(operatorValue, '+') != 0 || strcmp(operatorValue, '-') != 0 ||
         strcmp(operatorValue, '*') != 0 || strcmp(operatorValue, '/') != 0);
```

Comment: `'+'` is a small integer, not a pointer to the first element of a NUL-terminated array of `char`. That would be `"+"`.

Comment: You should be getting all sorts of compilation warnings from your compiler — about not passing pointers to `strcmp()` or converting integers to pointers.  If you are getting such compiler warnings, you should deal with them before asking on SO, or ask about how to resolve the compiler warnings if you don't understand them.  If you're not getting such warnings, you need to learn how to make your compiler give you warnings, and always use those options.  With GCC, consider using `-std=c11 -Werror -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes`.

Comment: thenk and sorry for asking a dump question

Comment: ...and when you've fixed all the things mentioned by the other comments, think about your comparison - as you've written it, it is always true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be easier to use the *strchr* function, defined as

```
char *strchr(const char *string, int c);
```

It finds the first occurrence of a character in a string. The character c can be the null character (\0); the ending null character of string is included in the search. Returns NULL if the character is not found.
See the following page for a full description and example of use

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rtref/strchr.htm

```
char target = "+-*/";
....
} while  (strchr(target, (int) operatorValue)) ==0); // loops until it gets a match
```

Then if you want to add more characters to the search string it is easy.

Answer (score 1):

operator value is char. you can't use string functions with I

```
    while (operatorValue != '+' ||  ....
```

Comment: may be also propose the OP to replace `scanf("%c", &operatorValue);` by `scanf(" %c", &operatorValue);` to bypass possible separators like a newline coming from the previous input thank to the space before "%c" ?